# What does Ravi Zacharias mean when he says "Intent is always prior to content"?

Tags: apologetics

I am a constant listener to [Ravi's Podcasts](http://www.rzim.org/podcasts/) and he always says "Intent is always prior to content." What does that mean?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to C.SE! When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). This is a really good first question.  It might be better if you would link to context so that others can help ferret out the meaning, but this is wonderful. +1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ravi Zacharias is a renown apologist for the Christian faith.  I, too, enjoy listening to him.  His account of his interview with the Grand Mufti of the Islam faith, which he describes as perhaps the most tension-fraught interview he has ever conducted, is unforgettable.

Since Mr. Zacharias is an astute apologist, I am guessing that his phrase "Intent is always prior to content" is a good "mantra" for anyone aspiring to be an apologist and a witness for Christ.  Before one opens his or her mouth in defense of the faith, a good question to ask oneself is,

> "Now, why am I about to defend the faith?  Is my intent to make myself look good by out-arguing the person with whom I am engaged in conversation, or is my intent first, to build a bridge of communication with my interlocutor, and second, to bear witness to the truth in Christ Jesus, but in a spirit of love, gentleness, and godly fear?"

If your intent is the former, then you should probably not open your mouth; you'll do more harm than good.  If on the other hand you are genuinely interested in hearing the person out, responding appropriately in a Spirit-led way, and all the while being in an attitude of prayer and dependence on God, then you are probably in a position to accomplish something for God.

Remember, our task is not to make ourselves look good, but to make our Savior look good.  Moreover, achieving eloquence and thus acquitting ourselves in a prideful way must never be the goal; pointing to Jesus is.

> "If I can speak in the tongues of men and of angels, but have not love, I am simply a noisy gong or a clanging cymbal" (Paul, 1 Corinthians 13).

Comment: In biblical support of this, Matthew 7:1-5 tells us to refrain from judging the other person. Instead, we should see the "splinter" in their eye from the perspective of having first had a similar "beam" removed from our eye. So we identify with them as fallen and show them how Christ removed the beam from us. "Jesus helped me, and I know He can help with your problem, too!" Identifying with them as fallen sinners helps us refrain from judging or false motives, and aids in moving in love.

Comment: @Steve:  Your observations are spot on.  Thank you for them.  Don